# How to skip an iteration in a for loop? | GDScript

Tags: for-loop, godot, gdscript

I want to skip an iteration of a for loop (but only sometimes so just increasing 'i' by 2 every time won't work).
I have something like this:

```
for i in range(5):
print(i)
if i == 2:
    i += 1
```

and I would want it to print:

```
0
1
2
4
```

but this doesn't work this way and it will just print: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.
I guess this is because you are iterating through an array and of course it makes sense why it doesn't work then.
But in other languages like Java or JavaScript this would work perfectly fine so I don't know if I am doing something completly wrong here.

Here is an example of what I would write in JavaScript and what it would print:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    console.log(i);
    if(i === 2)
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Console:**

```
0
1
2
4
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is because `for i in range(...)` doesn't work the same as the JavaScript code you wrote. No matter what you do to `i` in the middle of your loop, at the top it will always be reset to the next number in the sequence. In this case it's a sequence of numbers from 0 to 4, but you could just as easily iterate over an array or even a dictionary.

@Choubada's suggestion should work. It would look like this:

```gdscript
for i in range(5):
    if i == 2:
        continue

    print(i)
```

By putting the `if...continue` statement at the very top, you will effectively skip that iteration.

Comment: This method sadly doesn't work for what i want to use it for so i just used a while loop instead of for loop and increased 'i' manually. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `continue` keyword, which skip ther current iteration

Doncumentation: https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: This won't work as continue just skips all the code behind the statement but 'i' will still continue just as it would normally. It would print: 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: First of all, you need to print i at the end of the loop ( it will be printed even if we skip the iteration, because it's placed before the if statement ). Then, you don't want to print 3, but your condition is checking if i = 2, that doesn't make sense, change it to = 3. In general, we don't like changing our i value, we would prefer use the continue keyword. After all those changes your code now won't output 3

Comment: I am aware of this and i know that if I would place the print statement behind the continue that it would print what I want. Sadly this wouldn't solve my real problem for which i would need to actually skip an iteration completely just like it would in JavaScript or Java (see in my example at the end).

Comment: I will propably just change my for loop into an while loop so I can change 'i' manually if ther is no way to actually skip an iteration in gdscript.